# Xamarin Geocoding Placemark Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, geocoding

I am creating a project where getting the users' address are involve. I tried using the `Xamarin.Essentials` `Geolocation` (to get the coordinates) and `Geocoding` (to get the placemarks via coordinates). I am successful at getting the coordinates through geolocation (returns `Location`) but I get an exception on getting the placemark. I can't seem to find the main source of the problem in the internet.

Here is the Exception:

```
**Java.IO.IOException:** 'doqz: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.925084576s. [closed=[], open=[[buffered_nanos=4926319970, waiting_for_connection]]]'
```

Here is my code below. (I simplified it to only get the placemark from a given coordinate and still produce the same exception on my end):

**LocationServices.cs**

```
public class LocationServices
{
    private static LocationServices _LocationClientInstance;
    public static LocationServices LocationClientInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_LocationClientInstance == null)
                _LocationClientInstance = new LocationServices();
            return _LocationClientInstance;
        }
    }
    public async Task<Placemark> getPlacemark(Location coordinates)
    {
        Placemark result = null;
        try
        {
            var placemarks = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(coordinates.Latitude, coordinates.Longitude);
            result = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Cant Get Placemark", $"Cant Get Placemark\n{e.Message}", "OK");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        getLocCom = new AsyncCommand(getPlacemarkTry);
    }
    private string _loc;
    public string loc
    {
        get => _loc;
        set => SetProperty(ref _loc, value);
    }
    public ICommand getLocCom { get; }
    private async Task getPlacemarkTry()
    {
        Location current = new Location(14.58300883983523, 121.11321186835512);
        var result = await LocationServices.LocationClientInstance.getPlacemark(current);
        loc = await LocationServices.LocationClientInstance.getLocation(result);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
        <Label Text="Location Sample" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
    </Frame>
    <Button Text="Get Location" Command="{Binding getLocCom}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding loc}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I have a feeling that it only shows on my end. Please pitch in some of your suggestions and solution regarding this problem. Thank you

Comment: that sounds like a timeout issue

Comment: there are numerous posts about `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` being a timeout problem within the Google Cloud